# how to use clojure session in org mode?

Tags: emacs, clojure, org-mode

I wrote [this org document](https://gist.github.com/crinklywrappr/9e7c3dbbe5e564c648bda56ae160c9b9) to learn about literate programming w/ org mode.  I like it, but w/o a session the development experience is subpar.

`org-babel-initiate-session` yields `No org-babel-initate-session for clojure!`.  But because I can execute the code blocks for output I believe my setup is correct.

How do I get a clojure session going?

Comment: I believe you need [inf-clojure](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/inf-clojure) but this is based on guesses made by reading snippets from `ob-clojure.el` so my understanding is most probably incorrect/incomplete.

Comment: @NickD thanks.  If that's the case then I think I'm done.  `inf-clojure` is pretty nice but cider is *much* more featureful.  I think I will stick with Cider.  :-)

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions at https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-clojure.html  ?

Comment: Not 100% b/c some of that documentation is incompatible with Spacemacs.  I did however test w/ the documented `require`'s & check that `org-babel-clojure-backend` was set to `'cider`.

Comment: Do you need multiple org-babel sessions? If not, try  first running `M-x cider-jack-in` (instead of `org-babel-initiate-session`), and then `C-c C-c` in the code/src block.  This seems to work in a stock emacs.  Not sure about Spacemacs.